# Footer won't stick to bottom of page in windowed mode

Tags: html, css

I've tried countless of tips from previous questions but none seemed to work for me.

You can preview this issue at http://www.tusenskona.fi/, try resizing the window and you'll see what I'm talking about! The same issue can be seen on every page.

If you visit the galleri5 which is located under "Produkter" => "Dop" you can also see there's empty space under the footer.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code if anyone could take a look it's of the index page. The slideshow isn't playing on the jsfiddle site but the issue is still visible.

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/m875L6ot/5/'
```

Comment: Too many issues in that code to consider fixing... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 700px;` from `#pagewrap` and give `position: relative;`

So, it looks like:

```
#pagewrap {
    background-image: url("img/noisebg.png");
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: But it seems to break the index page when used, works like magic for the gallery though. For the index page it completely removes the pagewrap (white space where I've placed my content)

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I was able to apply it to the index site and do a couple tweaks and I got the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue of css in background image property.

Remove `background-size: cover;` property from **galleri.css** in **line 26**. 
 
**Original Code :**

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Replace code :**

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is working.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me at all. But thanks for your time!